# Mercurial marks unmodified files as modified in working directory and fails to revert

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg

Our team uses TortoisHg 2.0.5 on Windows and after refreshing file list in working directory it sometimes (at least once a day :(( ) shows a list of unmodified files as modified. Manual comparison doesn't show any changes in code, line breaks are also equal. Reverting of these "fantom" files causes no result. There a two way how we deal with this problem:

1. Turning off eol extension and reverting the files,
2. Manually removing the files and update them from the head revision.

It's really annoying to do this every day (twice ...three times... per day), especially on large changeset! Please help to find a reason of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried running hg diff? What is the output?

Answer (score 7):

The first question is, are you working exclusively on Windows, and if so, are you sure you need the `eol` extension?

As for the problem you're seeing, from [this series of emails](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/Line-endings-and-whitespace-issues-on-Windows-td1407347.html), it looks like the `eol` extension uses `LF` as its default *repository* encoding, which probably makes Mercurial think your created-on-Windows, CRLF-ending files have changed. To change this, add the following section to your `.hgeol` file:

```
[repository]
native = CRLF
```

I tried the following test, similar to the one in my link (with `eol` extension enabled):

```
> hg init eols
> cd eols
# used notepad++ to save a test file "foo" with Windows line endings (CRLF)
> hg commit -Am "added foo with CRLF"
> hg status
> echo [patterns] > .hgeol
> echo ** = native >> .hgeol
> hg status
  M foo       # spurious difference!
  ? .hgeol
> echo [repository] >> .hgeol
> echo native = CRLF >> .hgeol
> hg status
  ? .hgeol
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the mail list. Our team faced the same problem except we are working in Windows environment only. We have problems with Unix line endings since the first update (clone) of Mercurial repository. Visual Studio signalized that a lot of files have CR line endings. So we have considered that Mercurial stores files with Unix line endings in repository and now use eol extension to deal with the problem.

Comment: Does this solution help you at all?