# Mercurial creates unversioned copies of files during update to different branch

Tags: mercurial, branch

A little while ago I noticed that hg started creating unversioned copies of files in the repository at seemingly random times when I update between branches.  I can't for the life of me think of what I might have changed for this to start happening.  There is nothing in the verbose or trace output to indicate that these files are being created.

The new unversioned filenames all end with what seems to be a random string added to the end of the extension:

```
file1.txt-23121dd1  
someotherfile.sql-bc769bd2  
bizarrofile.cs-40a93ed0
hgisinvadingurhead.ppt-f8e9015a
```

When trying to determine the pattern of this happening I've noticed the following:

- The added characters in the filenames do not correspond with any changeset ID in the repository.  I have done a `grep -i` to the output of `hg history` and the string in the filename does not appear anywhere in the output.
- In all cases the files existed in the branch I was working on but do not exist in the branch I update to.
- Sometimes it's only one or two files, sometimes it's several.
- It is never the case that these are all of the files that exist in one branch but not the other.
- It is never the case that it is the same set of unversioned files between updates.
- Others on my team who are cloning the same repositories do not seem to be experiencing this

I thought maybe it was something within the repository but it also happens in other existing repositories and in brand new ones as well.

For example, I have done this (hg output omitted except for hg status output at the end, but no errors come from the output):

```
c:\> mkdir repo
c:\> cd repo
c:\repo\> hg init
c:\repo\> echo default > default.txt
c:\repo\> hg add
c:\repo\> hg commit -m "Commit default"
c:\repo\> hg branch branch1
c:\repo\> echo branch1 > branch1.txt
c:\repo\> hg add
c:\repo\> hg commit -m "Commit branch1"
c:\repo\> hg update default
c:\repo\> hg status
? branch1.txt-23121dd1
```

This is not repeatable every time.  I could repeat these steps and sometimes the unversioned file will be there at the end and sometimes it won't.  It's very sporadic.  In larger repositories, though, I almost always see at least one unversioned file between branch updates.

Full output of `hg update default` follows.  The output always displays as such whether or not the unversioned file is created.

```
resolving manifests
calling hook preupdate.eol: <function preupdate at 0x0000000002571668>
removing branch1.txt
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

I was using an older version of hg when I first noticed it but the problem still exists after updating to 2.3.2.  I am using Windows 7 Pro x64 with TortoiseHG 2.5.1 x64.  I don't think it's related to Tortoise, however, because I can replicate the problem by just using hg from the command line.

The contents of my mercurial.ini file are:

```
[ui]
username=myname <myname@mydomain.com>
ignore=C:\users\myusername\.hgignore
verbose=true
trace=true

[eol]
native = CRLF
only-consistent = False

[extensions]
purge =
eol =
```

I can live with it, but it's a pain to make sure I'm not accidentally adding these files to the repository in changesets with other new files.

If someone has seen this and could point me to the culprit I'd be most appreciative!

Comment: Please, show **full output** of `hg up default`

Comment: @Lazy I've edited it in.  Let me know if that's not what you were looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, file removed (as I saw in my case). I can only suspect now preupdate hook and backside-effect of it - I haven't any hooks (and troubles on update)

Comment: I get this same issue.  I'll get it from switching branches or even renaming a file.

Answer (score 0):

If a file is in use when updating between changesets, the in-use file is renamed with the added numbers so the update can succeed.

Comment: I thought of that as well.  The files in the example in my question are never opened.  None of the files are ever open.

Answer (score 0):

Does disabling the `eol` extension help matters? I noticed that your test did not use a `.hgeol` file as well (that's one of the things associated with [this extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EolExtension)). There's [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464824/mercurial-marks-unmodified-files-as-modified-in-working-directory-and-fails-to-r) hereabouts that is dedicated to some problems with this extension.

Comment: I will check on that.  I do have a .hgeol file in the other real repositories but I'm open to check anything at this point.