# Make Mecurial discard uncommitted changes

Tags: mercurial, eol

Is the following normal Mercurial behaviour? If so, how do I discard uncommitted changes?

```
D:\hgrepo\trunk>hg st
M Library\libFunc.h

D:\hgrepo\trunk>hg revert --all
reverting Library\libFunc.h

D:\hgrepo\trunk>hg st
M Library\libFunc.h

D:\hgrepo\trunk>hg update 1003 --clean               # Parent branch
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

D:\hgrepo\trunk>hg st
M Library\libFunc.h

D:\hgrepo\trunk>hg revert --all
reverting Library\libFunc.h

D:\hgrepo\trunk>hg st
M Library\libFunc.h
```

Additionally, a diff appears to show there are no modifications to the files (kdiff3 reports binary equal), but Mercurial still reports them as modified. (Only in reality I have about 50 modified files - I trimmed the example to a single file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have expected the second call to `hg st` in your example to list only a new untracked `libFunc.h.orig` file. Have you enabled the `eol` extension in your setup? There's [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464824/mercurial-marks-unmodified-files-as-modified-in-working-directory-and-fails-to-r) hereabouts that is dedicated to some problems with this extension.

Comment: Yes, that probably explains it.