# Mercurial: Ignore file attributes

Tags: mercurial

After update from remote repository mercurial detects modifications into just updated files, but external diff shows that content of files are the same. `hg diff` shows that all lines were removed and than added, different only in creation file timespan. How can I say mercurial don't detect changes like it, because they don't sense?

Comment: 99% that you have changed the end of line character (from `\n` to `\r\n` or vice versa). Check the external diff tool settings. So answering to your question - just setup your editor properly so that it didn't modify the files that way.

Comment: Is it an eol issue? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6465929/6309)

Comment: I think no. I have enabled `eol` extension and users which work with repository use only Windows.

Comment: `eol` extension is more harm than good. for `eol` extension to work properly every one of the repository editors should have it enabled. I'd suggested you to turn it off and start using editors/IDEs that don't break files (or set up them properly). PS: "I think" --- do you "think" or "know for sure"? ;-)

Comment: if I would know for sure I would answer question. No? :)
This is not `\r\n` issue. I have check both version have `CRLF`

Comment: @Dis Shishkov: what is the difference between an old and a new line then? "I have check both version have CRLF" -- have you turned off `eol` extension before that?

Comment: I checked into external tool (beyond compare). Have just turned off `eol` extension as you suggested, and have a weird result `hg diff` shows that all lines in modified file will be removed and no one for adding.

Comment: @Dis Shishkov: that means you have deleted file contents